Unable to Select Tables from Newly Added Schema in Workspace
I've recently added another schema to my workspace, but I'm encountering an issue where I can't select tables from this new schema. Currently, I can only switch between my two schemas, but I can't access the tables directly. Do I need to set specific GRANT permissions for each object in order to select the tables? Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.
Tried to select the Table from another schema in my application but i found no table or view.

"Do I need to set specific GRANT permissions for each object in order to select the tables?" Yes

@MTO I'm pretty sure this is not the case in APEX. Once you add a schema to your workspace all tables are visible, no explicit grants needed - I believe APEX does an ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA
